# Apache and mod_wsgi returning 504 error when posting specific SVG string

Tags: apache-2.2, http, mod-wsgi, 504

I have a wierd 504 error occuring in Apache + mod_wsgi when I post a specific SVG string. The backend application is Python Flask, but it does not seem to get to the application at all.

Here is one request that returns a 504 error:

```
curl 'https://some.domain.com/api/export/png' --data 'svg=%22%3E%28style'
```

And here is another one that returns with 200:

```
curl 'https://some.domain.com/api/export/png' --data 'svg=%22%3E%28styl'
```

The difrrerence is that I only removed one character from the POST data

The SVG data is cut down to the smallest one that could produce an error. The original SVG string is much larger.

The error that appears in the apache error log is:

```
[Tue Jun 09 14:27:26 2015] [error] [client 10.5.226.115] (104)Connection  reset by peer: mod_wsgi (pid=19254): Unable to get bucket brigade for request., referer: https://some.domain.com/
[Tue Jun 09 14:27:26 2015] [error] [client 10.5.226.115] mod_wsgi (pid=19252): Exception occurred processing WSGI script '/var/www/ade/src/interface.wsgi'.
[Tue Jun 09 14:27:26 2015] [error] [client 10.5.226.115] IOError: failed to write data
```

I it is interestig that the the error appears in the error log imidietly after I make the request, before the post data upload finishes.

Here are the version numbers we have:

```
Apache/2.2.22 (Ubuntu) 
mod_ssl/2.2.22 
OpenSSL/1.0.1 
mod_wsgi/3.3 
Python/2.7.3
```

Any clues what might be causing this?

Answer (score 0):

Look in your httpd.conf file and increase the Timeout value.

```
Timeout 600
```

Save the file and restart apache.